# Pentaho integration with Ofbiz

Tags: pentaho, ofbiz

I am new to ofbiz and wanted to integrate pentaho, I am using ofbiz-13 along with JDK-7.

I tried putting pentaho component into hot-deply but getting this error on login

```
Expression section.linkUrl is undefined on line 55, column 66 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> assignment: url="/" + opentapsApplicationName + "/control/" + section.linkUrl [on line 55, column 7 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl] ---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression section.linkUrl is undefined on line 55, column 66 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl. at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124) at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118) at freemarker.core.AddConcatExpression._getAsTemplateModel(AddConcatExpression.java:98) at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:416) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189) at org.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.renderTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:218) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderHtmlTemplate(HtmlWidget.java:206) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget$HtmlTemplate.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:251) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:111) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$PlatformSpecific.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:1058) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:134) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:95) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:840) at freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:104) at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93) at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189) at org.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.renderTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:218) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderHtmlTemplate(HtmlWidget.java:206) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget$HtmlTemplate.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:251) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:111) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$PlatformSpecific.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:1058) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$DecoratorScreen.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:729) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$DecoratorScreen.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:729) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$IncludeScreen.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:633) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$DecoratorScreen.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:729) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:134) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:95) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenWidgetViewHandler.render(ScreenWidgetViewHandler.java:104) at org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.renderView(RequestHandler.java:849) at org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.doRequest(RequestHandler.java:562) at org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doGet(ControlServlet.java:228) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:270) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.pentaho.core.system.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Expression section.tabId is undefined on line 58, column 32 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> if-else [on line 58, column 5 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl] ---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression section.tabId is undefined on line 58, column 32 in component://opentaps-common/webapp/common/includes/applicationTabBar.ftl. at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124) at freemarker.core.ComparisonExpression.isTrue(ComparisonExpression.java:121) at freemarker.core.AndExpression.isTrue(AndExpression.java:68) at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:80) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:416) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189) at org.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.renderTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:218) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderHtmlTemplate(HtmlWidget.java:206) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget$HtmlTemplate.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:251) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:111) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$PlatformSpecific.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:1058) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$Section.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:232) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreen.renderScreenString(ModelScreen.java:398) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:134) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderer.render(ScreenRenderer.java:95) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:840) at freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:104) at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93) at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189) at org.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.renderTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:218) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderHtmlTemplate(HtmlWidget.java:206) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget$HtmlTemplate.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:251) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.HtmlWidget.renderWidgetString(HtmlWidget.java:111) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget$PlatformSpecific.renderWidgetString(ModelScreenWidget.java:1058) at org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ModelScreenWidget.renderSubWidgetsString(ModelScreenWidget.java:141) at
```

Can any one suggest something?

Comment: Seems you are using Opentaps, not OFBiz?

Comment: yes i ma using opentaps-1.5 and there is no pentaho component in it.So can you please help me to integrate pentaho as well as generate a report